# Make a portion of code wait

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to simulate a cashpoint in visual basic and it's been going okay, I've got buttons from 1-9 and a clear key set up but I removed the code to shorten it for here. I was wondering if there was any alternative ways to make a section of code change when a MsgBox was closed with OK. The section I wish to change specifically is:

If Label1.Text = "Please wait.." 
Then
Label1.Text = "Proceed to enter your pin."
End If

which is in the code below, I've tried to use: Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) but all it does is cause the entire program to freeze until it's done and then carries on to do the whole script. What I really want it to do is change the text in Label1 to what I've already attempted. It might be horribly easy to do but I'm still new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim buttonArray = {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0, btnClear}

    For Each button In buttonArray
        button.Enabled = False
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim buttonArray = {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0, btnClear}
    barProgress.Increment(5)
    If barProgress.Value = 100 Then
        For Each Button In buttonArray
            Button.Enabled = True
        Next
        Timer1.Stop()
        MsgBox("Please insert your pin into our secure system.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnInsertCard_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsertCard.Click
    Timer1.Start()

    Label1.Text = "Please wait.."

    If btnInsertCard.Text = "Insert Your Card" Then
        btnInsertCard.Text = "Please wait.."
    End If

    If Label1.Text = "Please wait.." Then
        Label1.Text = "Proceed to enter your pin."
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That is a bit confusing. You want to simulate a 5 seconds pause between `Label1.Text = "Please wait.."` and `Label1.Text = "Proceed to enter your pin."` while not freezing the interface?

Comment: I want the label to change once the user has clicked OK on the message box that comes up once the progress bar gets to 100.

Comment: So put `Label1.Text = "Please wait.."` inside `Timer1_Tick` after the `MsgBox`?